# change calendar icon color in MUI Date & Time Picker v4

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker

I'm working on to add DateTimePicker to a project built with node v14, due to old dependancies I had to use older versions of MUI,
I'm trying to change icon color of the DateAndTimePicker, but my tries so far doesn't work so far.

below is the component code for the DateAndTimePickers

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        container: {
            display: 'flex',
            flexWrap: 'wrap',
            width: '100%'
        },
        textField: {
            // marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
            // marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
            width: '100%', // Set width to 100% of parent component
            '& .MuiInputBase-root': {
                color: 'white', // Change text color
                '&:hover': {
                    '&:before': {
                        borderBottom: 'none', // Remove underline when hovering
                    },
                },
                '&:before': {
                    borderBottom: 'none', // Remove underline
                },
                '&:after': {
                    borderBottom: 'none', // Remove underline when focused
                },
            },
            "& .MuiButtonBase-root": {
                color: '#ffffff',
            },
            "& .MuiInput-icon": {
                color: '#ffffff'
            },
            "& .MuiSelect-icon": {
                color: '#ffffff'
            },
            "& .MuiInputBase": {
                color: '#ffffff'
            },

        },

    }),
);

export default function DateAndTimePickers() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <form className={classes.container} noValidate>
            <TextField
                id="datetime-local"
                // label="Next appointment"
                type="datetime-local"
                defaultValue="2024-05-24T10:30"
                className={classes.textField}
                InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,
                }}
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
            />
        </form>
    );
}
```